# Pin image background to bottom of document in short and long documents

Tags: html, background

I'm trying to fix an image to the bottom of the **document** for a HTML page.

My strategy roughly involves a setting the CSS height of the html node to 100%, and setting the background-position of the background-image to bottom.

This works for pages with a document shorter than the viewport size, but for documents with a length greater than the viewport size, the background is positioned in the middle of the page.

Without knowing whether the document will be longer than the viewport or not, how can I fix the background at the end of the document?

I've managed to get it working as required in Firefox only with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<style type="text/css"> 
* { 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
} 

html { 
    height:100%; 
} 

.wrapper {
    background: #eaeaea url(ufford-logo.jpg) scroll repeat-x bottom center; 
    min-height: 100%;
}

</style> 
 </head> 
 <body>

  <div class="wrapper">

        <p style="height: 2000px;">test</p>

  </div>

 </body> 
</html>
```

The inline style on the p tag simulates a long document.

Comment: You should probably change your title and re-tag your question. It seems like you're trying to pin your image to the bottom of the viewport and not the bottom of the document as said in the title. Afaik you'll need JavaScript to do so, so you might want to add this tag.

Comment: I agree, your example seems to do exactly what you say you want.  The problems occur when the document is shorter than the viewport size, so it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.  If you're looking to guarantee the page is it least one viewport in height, try setting both body and html to 100% height.

Comment: I'm trying to pin the image to the bottom of the document, not the viewport. Indeed the problem occurs when the document is shorter than the viewport size and this is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me in Firefox 3.5, IE8/7c, Chrome 2. Doesn't work in Opera 10b but I would expect it to work in the stable version (9.6).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<style type="text/css">
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    background: #eaeaea url(http://sstatic.net/so/img/so/logo.png) scroll repeat-x bottom center;
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>
 </head>

 <body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p style="height: 2000px;">test</p>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant, I'd clearly just missed the right combination of min-heights and heights on elements. Your demo works fine, and IE6 can easily be supported with height on the .wrapper

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to achieve is very similar to [this layout](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html), though in your case you would just stick your image into the footer element (or have it as a background on the footer).  If you have a more complex page layout you may be able to adapt the code, or you could try [this approach using javascript](http://blog.corunet.com/english/three-column-layout-with-full-page-height).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick something to the bottom of the visible window, you can do so using CSS. This will work on render (and on window resize).

```
#specialBackground {
    background-image: url(bg.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This will place the image where you want it - you will need to change the background-image and the height appropriate to your image. The z-index places the division behind other content, but it doesn't hurt to define the division earlier in your document too (you can define it anywhere and the position will be unchanged).

To keep the division at the bottom of the viewport when the visitor scrolls the page, you'll need to use JavaScript. Example below:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
document.getElementById("specialBackground").style.bottom = 
    (document.body.scrollTop * -1) + "px";
};
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: I don't know if I made this clear - but you don't use your "wrapper" division to do this - you add another empty division, which get's placed behind the wrapper because of the CSS rules. So you'd have this on your page:

```
<div id="specialBackground">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="wrapper">
...
```